# Distinct count of values based on date in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table like shown below:

| ID | Date | Asset | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 145 | 7/29/22 | A | Market |
| 145 | 7/30/22 | A | Warehouse |
| 145 | 7/29/22 | B | Market |
| 145 | 7/29/22 | C | Truck |
| 150 | 7/30/22 | B | Market |
| 145 | 7/29/22 | D | Market |
| 145 | 7/30/22 | A | Market |

What I am trying to accomplish is to get a distinct count of IDs for each date with a location filter as well.  So I would want a count of ID based on the slicer selected Date of 7/29/22 AND 7/30/22 for the Market Location.   The desired result is 2 for the selected dates from the date slicer which directly corresponds to the date column in the table.

I was trying to use this DAX formula and wasn't getting anywhere....

```
IDsMarket =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Products'[ID] ),
    ALL ( 'Products' )
)
```

I have a measure dropped onto a card. I should have specified that. My apologies. I need 1 measure to show me the combined count for the two days selected.

I tried this with countrows as well but of course the result wasn't distinct...  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: On 7/29/22 there is ID 145 only. What do you mean with "The desired result is 2 for the selected dates"?

Comment: Basically that I want the measure to realize that even though the ID number is the same, to count it twice because the date is different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you're looking for is

```
IDsMarket = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Products'[ID]),
    'Products'[Location] = "Market"
)
```

The resulting Table will look like this

[image]

But if you put the measure on a Card visual, you'll get

[image]

So in DAX the same measure can yield 1000 different values - depending on the **filter context**.

Comment: That works in a table, but I have a measure dropped onto a card.  I should have specified that.  My apologies.  I need 1 measure to show me the combined count for the two days selected.

Comment: What do you mean with `combined count`?

Comment: Because the user has the two dates selected in a slicer on the dashboard, I need the measure to add those counts together to be 3.  If the user selects a third date in the slicer, then the measure would add the count from that day as well and so on.

Comment: So now it's 3? For how long will you be changing your question?

Comment: You are right, I am sorry, my mind is all over the place trying to figure this out.  adding and deleting code constantly.  I've looked at too much for a day.  When I enter that exact code into PBI, it just returns a value of 1.  Not 2

Answer (score 1):

I created a conditional column in Power Query and combined the ID with the "day" number from the date column which allowed me to then do a distinct count on that combined custom column which produced to correct answer.  Sorry for all the confusion.  One of those days.

Comment: if Peter was correct answering your question, then you can upvote him at least, and if you messed with the question you can accept his answer.